# Glucose, Sugar level sensors

Tags: sensor, wearable

I have a hobbie project in which I'm trying to assemble a wearable health/fitness oriented device and I want to measure my blood sugar levels. I've visited this area first 5 years ago and technology wasn't there at a time. Does anyone know of any portable, non invasive (sound or light based, without taking blood) sensors to measure glucose/sugar level?

Cheers.

Comment: I believe that Google has developed a contact lens that can transmit blood glucose levels.  I know there have been lots of other experiments with patches and various wavelengths of light as (more or less) non invasive sensors, but none of these seems to have been satisfactory so far.

Comment: As a diabetic I would LOVE to see a noninvasive way to frequently measure (or even just estimate) my blood sugar throughout the day!  So I hope you find something that works.

Comment: The technology exists but is still quite experimental. A company, who's name escapes me, produced an optical system with a laser and spectral analysis system which was certified in Europe but the company imploded before they started shipping product. a current Google search for "non-invasive blood glucose monitoring" brings up an Israeli company working on an ear lobe optical monitoring system, still years away from availability. It is a hard problem and the techniques used are probably out of reach of the typical hobbiest.